# Using a function for a list by lapply instead of a for loop

Tags: r, lapply

I have a for loop of a list (L) which works well as follow, but I want to replace loop by lapply function.

```
library(mgcv)
library(MuMIn)
library(dplyr)

L1 = data.frame(x1 = c(1:30) , x2 = c(3:32) , x3 = c(1:30) , Y = c(1:30))
L2 = data.frame(x1 = c(2:31) , x2 = c(4:33) , x3 = c(1:30) , Y = c(1:30) )
L=list(L1,L2)

options(na.action = "na.fail")
for (i in 1:length(L)){
  S = as.data.frame(L[[i]])
  fit = gam(Y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3) ,  data = S)
  dd  = dredge(fit , rank = BIC )[1]
  M_1 = get.models(dd, subset = 1)[[1]]
  R_gam = predict(M_1 , data=S , type = "response")
}
```

the lapply function does not work in following codes:

```
Mygam <- function(df){
  S2 = as.data.frame(df)
  fit = gam(Y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3) ,  data = S2)
  dd  = dredge(fit , rank = BIC )[1]
  M_1 = get.models(dd, subset = 1)[[1]]
  ET_gam = predict(M_1 , data=S2 , type = "response")
}

R_gam = L %>% lapply(Mygam)
```

Comment: It does return something for me, what is your expected output?

Comment: Does the Mygam function (second part of the codes) work? @Maël

Answer (score 1):

When calling your function `Mygam` I get the following error

```r
> Mygam(df=L1)
Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'S2' not found
```

If `S2` is defined in your GlobalEnv the function works so I assume one of the objects in your function that uses the `S2` dataframe doesn't work inside a function environment.

So the problem is not the `lapply` but the function itself.

A possible workaround would be to define S2 in the GlobalEnvironment so all objects can use it.

```r
Mygam <- function(df){
  #S2 <- as.data.frame(df)
  assign("S2", data.frame(df), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  fit <- gam(Y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3) ,  data = S2)
  dd  <- dredge(fit , rank = BIC )[1]
  M_1 <- get.models(dd, subset = 1)[[1]]
  ET_gam <- predict(M_1 , data=S2 , type = "response")
}
```

But the better solution would be to understand why the `prediction` function call and the objects used in it do not find the `S2` object when called inside the function.